# Spring MVC HTTP 404 Not Found / HTTP 405 Method Not Found

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. Have been trying to solve this for a while now (many hours).

I run this login form. I displays right, but when submitted shows 404 Not Found.

web.xml -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>LoginApp-SpringMVC-Part1</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login.spring</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.webform.controller" ></context:component-scan>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property
            name="prefix"
            value="/" >
        </property>
        <property
            name="suffix"
            value=".jsp" >
        </property>
    </bean>
  </beans>
```

LoginController.java -->

```
package com.webform.controller;



import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Login.spring")
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processCredentials(@RequestParam("userName")String userName,@RequestParam("password")String password) {
        String message = "Invalid credentials";
        if(!userName.equals("") && !password.equals("")) {
            if(userName.equals(password)) {
                message = "Welcome " + userName + "!!";
            }
        }
        return new ModelAndView("list","message",message);
    }
}
```

index.jsp -->

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html>  
 <head>  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  
  <title>Login Form</title>  
 </head>  
 <body>  
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form method="POST" action="Login.spring">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="userName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
         <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>  
        </tr> 
    </table>
  </form>  
   </body>  
</html>
```

Now if I change `<url-pattern>/Login.spring</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>*/Login.spring</url-pattern>` in web.xml, then it gives me 405 Method Not Found 
Thank you in Advance.

Regards

Comment: If you're new, I recommend skipping all the legacy bits (`web.xml`, XML-based context configuration, external containers) and using Spring Boot, which will do all of the setup for you. (Additionally, for this specific case, use Spring Security instead of doing things by hand.)

Comment: ok. Thanks. will try that as well. Can you help me with this one?

Comment: You say "it displays right"--with what request address? Turn logging on `DispatcherServlet` to DEBUG--what does it say?

Comment: Its shows the form on http://localhost:8080/webform/
But 405 on http://localhost:8080/webform/Login.spring

Comment: What is the location of your `jsp` pages?

Comment: jsp location is at root of WEB-INF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my problem was the tomcat and jdk version.

Minimum configuration needed: 
Tomcat : v7.0
JDK : 1.7.x

Answer (score 1):

Change your `<url-pattern>/Login.spring</url-pattern>` to
`<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>` in web.xml.
And first try to map at method level instead of class level like this:
`@RequestMapping(value="/Login.spring",method = RequestMethod.POST)`

Comment: Then it is something related to mapping.

Comment: Try to modify your structure and code based on this tutorial : http://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/

Comment: Thanks this one helped a lot.. it was my tomcat version.